How Do You Make A Foreground Service Notification Only Appear When The App Is Closed Or In The Background In Android?
As the title says, how do you make a foreground service notification only appear if the app is closed or in the background?
I have a sample app I'm trying to implement that feature into to but I don't know where to start.
The sample app consists of a button in the middle of the screen. When the button is pressed a notification appears at the top.
Here it is
This is the application class called "NotificationApplication". It contains the notification channel and manager. I have it registered in the Android Manifest.
class NotificationApplication: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            "notification_channel_id",
            "Notifications",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as 
        NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    }
}

This is the service class called "NotificationService". It contains the function to start the notification. I added the service name and foreground service type into the Android Manifest.
class NotificationService: Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent?.action) {
            "Start" -> start()
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private fun start() {

            val notification =
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this@NotificationService, "notification_channel_id")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle("Background Service")
                    .setContentText("Service is running in background")
                    .build()

            startForeground(1, notification)
        }
    }

Here is the Main Activity. It contains the user interface and intent to display notification.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    Intent(applicationContext, NotificationService::class.java).also {
                        it.action = "Start"
                        startService(it)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Show Notification If App Is Closed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I've added the following permissions into the Android Manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

How do I modify the code to have the notification or the entire foreground service only start when the app is closed or in the background?

A running Foreground Service always needs to show a notification, nevertheless if the app is in foreground or in background.
What you can do, is not to start the foreground service when you click the button, but set a flag, and then listen to the lifecycle of the app.
First you have to implement a OnLifeCycleEvent Composable like this:
@Composable
fun OnLifecycleEvent(onEvent: (owner: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit) {
    val eventHandler = rememberUpdatedState(onEvent)
    val lifecycleOwner = rememberUpdatedState(LocalLifecycleOwner.current)

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner.value) {
        val lifecycle = lifecycleOwner.value.lifecycle
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { owner, event ->
            eventHandler.value(owner, event)
        }

        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
} 

Then, in setContent {...} you can call it and listen to the lifecycle events like ON_PAUSE or ON_RESUME.
In the specific case, you then check if the flag, you set by clicking the button is true, and only then you start the foreground service.
Example:
OnLifecycleEvent { _, event ->
    when (event) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
            if (flag) {
                Intent(applicationContext, NotificationService::class.java).also {
                    it.action = "Start"
                    startService(it)
                }
            }

        }

        else -> {
            /** Do nothing */
        }
    }
}


What do I put in the flag variable?

You can simply do a boolean value, like var flag by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }. And then in on the button click you simply do flag = true
